# As Duryodhana's Senapati did Bhishma carry out treachery and/or dereliction of duty by commission and/or omission?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma, bhishma, duryodhana

**1**. Bhishma kept Karna with his Vasavi Shakti out of the war for 10 days by his insulting ways. (If Karna had killed Arjuna, the war would have been over. Even if he wouldn't kill the Pandavas he could have killed some "name" warriors like Satyaki or Chekitana.)

**2**. It looks like all he did was to kill low-level warriors on the Pandava side making sure that the outcome of the war wasn't affected.

**3**. The most horrific attack in the war was the attack on Bhurishravas to deprive him of his fair victory over Satyaki - surely word must have reached Bhishma about this and he said nothing. He was constantly undermining Duryodhana for being adharmic, whereas Krishna constantly egged the Pandavas on to acts of adharma and even says so at the end of the war.

IMO, all of the above suggests Bhishma was more loyal to the Pandava side than Duryodhana.

Are there any instances where Bhishma proved his worthiness to Duryodhana?

Did Duryodhana ever acknowledge Bhishma's loyalty towards him and the side he was representing?

Comment: You are asking question in the title and giving answer in the body. We do not refute or debate the arguments made made by you. We are not a discussion forum to debate or discuss things. We only answer the questions asked properly. You should ask your questions properly. This is opinion based question as you are trying to establish your thoughts regarding this topic.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I don't know. It's up to OP to accept my edits so the question can be re-opened and answered objectively. If no response from OP, I assume they are ok with my edits.

Comment: @sv. Your edit takes the question which is similar to revision 5 which OP didn't ask in the revision 6. This is like a rollback without the OP's intent.

Comment: @sv. Are you joking? OP doesn't return for 1 month. You should first know the intent of the OP and then edit for reopening the question.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Since these are extraordinary situations we need extraordinary measures :D

Comment: @sv. No, you almost rollbacked the question into previous revision which OP changed in his next revision. All the edits should not conflict with the current revision of the OP. The question should not be edited and reopened by rolling back a revision without OP intent.

Comment: The question was not Bhishma being Dharmic. It is Bhishma being adarmic and treacherous towards Kauravas. You should edit with this question and not your question.

Comment: I see your point. Treacherous = Unfaithful to one's side = 'adharmic acts of omission and commison' ... Agree?

Comment: @sv, if your friend betrayed his employer, and you betray him and report him to the police, are you being treacherous ?

Comment: @Pandya It's unmoderator-like behavior to rollback edits without leaving a comment or having a discussion.

Comment: @ram It's all relative. My friend and his wife may see me as disloyal if I report him. Police may see me disloyal to the nation if I don't report my friend.

Comment: @sv. It is very un copy-editor like to rollback the OP question without his intent. You should first know the intent and then should edit. What you edited is revision 5 but OP himself removed and edited that revision when he was active. So, we should not edit with that question because it is not his question.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, Let's assume the OP's intent was bad. Yet, there was a good question lying inside the previous edits. The Qn looked better with the latest edits from sv. and 4 other people reopened this Qn, seeing the latest edits. Now, with the new rollback, you have voided the reopening of the Qn. This Qn is now again vulnerable for closure.

Comment: @iammilind The good question lying inside the question was already changed by OP himself in revision 6. If the question is bad, let it be bad. The OP will return and make it good based on our comments. Why should we rollback his own edits made to the question just to reopen and answer? OP's intent is important. We should not reopen a bad question which was made into a good question based on our assumptions. Such reopens are not recommended for the site.

Comment: @sv. Why are you so much interested in rollbacking the OP's question? Can't you see revisions 5 and 6? They are not the same. How are "Did Bhishma carry out adharmic acts of omission and commison in his Senapati duties towards Duryodhana?" and "Are there any instances where Bhishma carried out Senapati duties towards Duryodhana faithfully?" same?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma OP not able to comment on this matter is a problem with the system. No point in discussing it over & over. The question now belongs to the community. And if anything can be salvaged from it, we should, to make it relevant to others.

Comment: @sv. Question should not be salvaged by putting your question into the OP's question. If OP not responding is a fault in system, then propose a feature request on main meta. Same rules apply when the OP is suspended, active or inactive. You should not change the question completely. You should not edit question to suit your answer.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma "You should not change the question completely." - You are saying 2 different things now, your first comment says OP was making a statement, starting a debate, etc instead of asking a question. What I tried to do is, change it in to a question. Neither you nor the mod put in any effort in to turning this into an objective question.

Comment: @sv.  I didn't because I don't know whether he was already  making a debate or asking a real question. That is why I didn't do that. If i get  a reply, I will do that. If you want to make a question then change by making with current revision. See the latest question by OP. He was asking Whether Bhishma was unfaithful and immoral towards Duryodhana not whether he was moral and faitful towards Duryodhana. And also he didn't ask about instances where he supported Duryodhana.  If you are producing a question, do it from latest revision of OP not older ones.

Answer (score 1):

Bhishma allowed atrocities to happen under his watch which resulted in war. He chose loyalty to the King than service to the people, a violation of Dharma.

When a General sees his own side is violating the law what should he do ? Should he continue to serve that government ? Should he compromise with it for his personal comfort and status (vow to his father's father-in-law) ?

Bhishma chose his comfort and status over Dharma. It doesn't indicate his loyalty to Kauravas or Pandavas or Dharma but his own sense of "grandeur".

I personally thing story of Bhishma is a lesson in "ego" not stopping is doing the right thing.

Answer (score -2):

In the US Army, a soldier is government property.  If he hurts himself, he is damaging US Government property.

By telling Duryodhnana's enemies how to eliminate him as a military asset of Duryodhana, Bhishma clearly committed treachery.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mahabharata/d/doc118439.html

> Replying to Yudhisthira's inquiry, Ganga's son said, "As long as I am
>   alive, O son of Pandu, you will not have victory. O possessor of great
>   wisdom, this is the fact of the matter. After I am slain, you will be
>   triumphant. If you, therefore, desire victory, then kill me without
>   delay. I give you permission to do so. You are fortunate to know my
>   position, for if you had not solicited my advice, then there would
>   have been days of misfortune ahead. Listen to my words, and act upon
>   what I say. With my large bow and other weapons, I fight very
>   carefully in battle. No one, not even the demigods headed by Indra,
>   can defeat me. If, however, I lay aside my weapons, then you may
>   defeat me. It is known that I will never fight with a woman or one who
>   was once a woman. The son of Drupada, Shikhandi, was once a woman in
>   his youth and has since attained manhood. Keep Shikhandi before
>   Arjuna, and let Arjuna release his arrows and pierce my body. I will
>   not fight with Shikhandi. At that time I will lay down my weapons, and
>   taking this opportunity, Arjuna may strike me on all sides and gain
>   victory. Except for Devaki's divine son, Lord Krishna, or Arjuna,
>   there is no one who can defeat me. After I am vanquished, you will be
>   able to defeat Dhritarastra's sons and their allies."

Comment: Why should Bhishma abide by the laws of US army?

Comment: In question you are asking `Are there any instances where Bhishma carried out Senapati duties towards Duryodhana faithfully?` while in answer you have not admitted anything either in support or in oppose. Btw US army is not relevant here.

Comment: If he had been serving in the US Army - he would have been summarily executed on the bed of arrows for collaborating with the enemy to put himself out of commission.  But we don't know which would have triumphed - his "Iccha-mrtyu" boon or the US Army.

Comment: Why would he serve in US Army?

Comment: Not an answer. US Army standards do not apply here. Yuddha Neeti of Mahabharata era is the measuring rod.